# Fluxbox battery monitor?

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, fluxbox

I'm using fluxbox on Arch, and I'm trying to put a battery monitor in the toolbar, next to the time.

gkrellm takes up too much space, and can't be configured in the toolbar, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [batterymon-clone](https://github.com/jareksed/batterymon-clone):

> Clone of BatteryMon, a simple GNOME applet to monitor battery status. This adds i18n support, a distutils based build infrastructure, etc. The homepage of the original software is at http://code.google.com/p/batterymon/

[A PKGBUILD is available](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=52974&comments=all).

Comment: The clone worked great, thanks. Is there a way to get rid of the icon and just use text? There doesn't seem to be an option for it.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer conky,

You may display a bar, or merely a percentage number:

> ```
>    battery_bar (height),(width) (num)
>           Battery percentage remaining of ACPI battery in a bar. ACPI bat‐
>           tery number can be given as argument (default is BAT0).
>
>    battery_percent (num)
>           Battery  percentage  remaining  for  ACPI battery.  ACPI battery
>           number can be given as argument (default is BAT0).
> ```

Comment: does this go in `~/.conkyrc` ?